# Junit test cases stopped executing after 2 test cases

Tags: java, hibernate, unit-testing, junit

[image]I am writing DBunit (junit of DAO methods) in Spring + Hibernate framework and using Java8.
I have many test cases in the Test class, which when run individually are  successful. But when I run that particular class, the test cases stops its execution at the 3rd test case by executing the 2 test cases. 
I tried shuffling the test cases, it takes up any method at random, it stops executing at the third test case.

The configuration is implemented properly, in the below snippet, it fails at the testCMethod test case.

```
public class ABCDAOTest extends Test case {


    @Override
    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
            super.setUp()
    }


    @Test
    public void testAMethod(){
        /*
            My test case
        */
    }

    @Test
    public void testBMethod(){
        /*
            My test case
        */
    }


    @Test
    public void testCMethod(){
        /*
            My test case
        */
    }


    @Test
    public void testDMethod(){
        /*
            My test case
        */
    }


    }
```

Please provide view your input.

Comment: That's not valid Java syntax, so I'm not sure how it's executing.

Comment: The snippet above is an example which i have made. Individual test cases are running properly in my actual scenario. Syntactically, its working correctly but failing after executing 2 test cases and stopping at the third.

Comment: The 'extends Test case' shouldn't be necessary assuming you are using junit annotation based

Comment: It's evident this is not your real code - you're not going to get any useful answers until you show it.

Comment: Besides that: "it fails at the testCMethod test case" is a pretty bad description of your problem. Consider posting real error messages, stack traces, the like. You are basically telling us "I got some code that is somehow failing". How on earth do you expect us to help upon such input?

Comment: added shanshot,,which shows no error

Answer (score 0):

To run the tests in a particular order you want it could be done like this

```
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;

import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;

@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
public class SampleTest {

    @Test
    public void firstTest() {
        System.out.println("first");
    }

    @Test
    public void secondTest() {
        System.out.println("second");
    }
}
```

Remember MethodSorters is an Enum whose other constants are

**JVM** - Leaves the test methods in the order returned by the JVM. Note that the order from the JVM may vary from run to run.

**DEFAULT** - Sorts the test methods in a deterministic, but not predictable, order.

and about not running the tests after second one, the probable reason can be the third test run might not be able to give result because of infinite loop.
So we can also restrict the runtime of a test case by adding a **Rule** and using Timeout, as used following

```
public class LongRunningTests {
@Rule
public Timeout globalTimeout = Timeout.seconds(5);
@Test
public void whatWeDoInATestMethodEchoesInEternity() {
while(true);
}
}
```

hope this can work for you.